# Use Inner Join to populate values in table columns

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem in populating the records of a table that has the foreign key of another table, where the disciple column should appear the value of its foreign key

[Table image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjqJK.png)

I made a query that makes the desired selection called `$fk`, but I don't know how to make it populate the foreach.

- `MasterController.php`

```
    public function index()
    {
        $master = MasterModel::paginate(5);
        $fk = DB::table('master')->join('fighter', 'fighter.id', '=', 'master.id_fighter')
        ->select('master.id', 'master.name', 'master.martial_art', 'master.nacionality',
        'master.genre', 'master.height', 'master.weight', 'fighter.name')->get();
        return view('master.master', compact(['master','fk']));
    }
```

- `table.php`

```
    @foreach ($master as $msf)
        <tr>
                <td> {{ $msf->id }} </td>
                    <td> {{ $msf->name}} </td>  
                    <td> {{ $msf->martial_art }} </td>  
                    <td> {{ $msf->nacionality }} </td>  
                    <td> {{ $msf->genre->value }} </td>
                    <td> {{ $msf->height }} m</td>  
                    <td> {{ $msf->weight }} kg</td>
                    <td> {{ $msf->id_hunter }} </td>
                    <td>
                        <form action="{{ url("delete-master/$msf->id") }}" method="POST">
                                <a href="{{ url("update-master/$msf->id") }}" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-arrows-rotate"></i>&nbsp;Update</a>
                                @csrf @method('DELETE')
                                <x-primary-button class="ml-3"> {{ __('Delete') }} </x-primary-button>  
                        </form>
                   </td>  
           </tr>   
    @endforeach
```

- MasterModel

```
    class MasterModel extends Model
    {
        use HasFactory;
        protected $table = 'master';
        protected $primary_key = 'id';
        public $timestamps = false;
        protected $fillable = [
            'name',
            'martial_art',
            'nacionality',
            'genre',
            'height',
            'weight',
            'id_fighter',
        ];
        protected $casts = [
            'genre' => Genre::class
        ];
        public function fighter(){
          return $this->belongsTo(
          Fighter::class, 
          'id_fighter', // foreign key of fighter table in master table  
          'id' // id fighter table
          );
        }
    }
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow gapih! i do curious, why did you call `$msf->id_hunter` but it wasn't in the `select` parameter? also, have you considered to use [tag:eloquent] instead?

Comment: What would be the best alternative?

Comment: where is this `id_hunter` come from?

Comment: @BagusTesa I'm embarrassed, I didn't notice this error.

Comment: its ok, everyone make mistakes.